# will_paginate with search function is not working in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I am trying to search my posts item with pagination. I am doing like this..

```
@posts = Post.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)
```

But it showing **NoMethodError**

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x9a93f08>
```

I don't know where i am wrong. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just change my code

```
@posts = Post.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)
```

to this

```
@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).search(params[:search])
```

Now it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

`params[:search])` gives you an array. And Array don't have `paginate` method, so errors thrown up. Use `p params[:search]).inspect` to see the same.

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to use [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) instead. As you can see by the [Readme](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/README.rdoc) there's one section on to paginate Arrays.
Also make sure you read the [Kaminari recipes](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/Kaminari-recipes) where is an example on paginate Arrays.